# How to Identify which Nvme m.2 already has windows installed when installing ubuntu on separate identical m.2 drive

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, nvme

this question may be ultra noob, sorry in advanced if it is.

I'm  trying to dual boot the latest Ubuntu LS on a separate m.2.

I already have windows 10 installed on a samsung evo 970 plus. I'm just about to install Ubuntu onto the empty evo plus but I cannot figure out which drive is which.

1. samsung evo 970 plus nvme0n1
2. samsung evo 970 plus nvme1n1

really trying to avoid taking the windows m.2 out. Do the number's at the end of the names mean something that I can compare to in windows to identify which is which? please note I am not partitioning anything. Linux is getting a full m.2 to itself.

Thank you

Comment: If you are installing Ubuntu Desktop, use the “Try Ubuntu” option to boot into a UI. From there, you can use Disks to see which NVMe device contains an NTFS partition. That will be your Windows device 

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: With two drives best to manually partition in advance so that you have an ESP on the Ubuntu drive. Default is to use an existing ESP which usually then is the Windows ESP. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator